# Unexpected output from using "create database"

Tags: sql, oracle, command-line-interface

My current task is to create a .bat file that can manually create an Oracle database, so that a Database Configuration Assistant is no longer necessary.

I am following [**this guide**](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/admin/creatingdbmanually.html).

I am stuck at "Creating the database". Upon typing:

```
SQL> create database ORA10
```

I do not get the expected output as described on the guide:

```
SQL>create database ora10
logfile   group 1 ('D:\oracle\databases\ora10\redo1.log') size 10M,
          group 2 ('D:\oracle\databases\ora10\redo2.log') size 10M,
          group 3 ('D:\oracle\databases\ora10\redo3.log') size 10M
character set          WE8ISO8859P1
national character set utf8
datafile 'D:\oracle\databases\ora10\system.dbf' 
          size 50M
          autoextend on 
          next 10M maxsize unlimited
          extent management local
sysaux datafile 'D:\oracle\databases\ora10\sysaux.dbf' 
          size 10M
          autoextend on 
          next 10M 
          maxsize unlimited
undo tablespace undo
          datafile 'D:\oracle\databases\ora10\undo.dbf'
          size 10M
default temporary tablespace temp
          tempfile 'D:\oracle\databases\ora10\temp.dbf'
          size 10M;
```

Instead I get a bunch of numbered input requests:

```
SQL> create database ORA10
  2 and
  3 it
  4 doesn't
  5 seem
  6 to
  7 stop
  8 asking
  9 for
  10 inputs
```

Other sources/guides I've googled look similar to the aforementioned guide. As far as I know (I might not be using the right keywords), my output is not supposed to happen. I am unable to identify what is going on here.

Please note that I don't actually know much about SQL or using command prompt. My background is limited to classroom HTML/CSS/Java/Python. I have been dared to complete a number of programming related tasks within a certain period of time (a week) without any instruction or preparation - though I am allowed to use the internet for assistance. So far so good until now.

Any assistance will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: `create database ora10;`? I think you may be incorrectly reading the rest as output though, the logfile and following rows are supposed to be a part of the command (up to the semicolon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*All* the lines in your listing from `create database ORA10` to `size 10M;` *including the last semicolon* are not output, but instead part of **one single statement**. The semicolon terminates it and tells the command interpreter to execute what you've written. Therefore it is continuing to ask you for input until you tell it you're done (with the semicolon).

If you simply want to create a database without specifying any other options, you can simply add a semicolon. The following will create a database with the name "ORA10" in the default configuration:

```
CREATE DATABASE ORA10;
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot more sense now.